# If $H$ anniliates a state, must $Q$ and $Q^\dagger$ also annihilate the state?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hilbert-space, hamiltonian, supersymmetry

Suppose we have a a Hamiltonian, $H$. And suppose also we have some operator $Q$ such that $\{Q, Q^{\dagger}\} = H$, and $Q^2 = 0$.

If we find a state $|\psi \rangle$ such that $Q|\psi \rangle = Q^{\dagger}|\psi \rangle = 0$, then it follows that $H|\psi\rangle = 0.$

My question is about the converse. That is, if there is some $|\phi \rangle$ such that $H |\phi \rangle = 0$, is it necessarily true that the $Q|\phi \rangle = Q^{\dagger}|\phi\rangle = 0$? And in particular, I am wondering if this is true for "non-normalisable" states.

Typically the argument seems to start by assuming we have some state $|\phi\rangle$ such that $H|\phi\rangle = E|\phi \rangle$. Then:

\begin{align*}
    E\langle \phi|\phi\rangle &= \langle \phi| H |\phi\rangle \\
    &= |Q|\phi\rangle|^2 + |Q^{\dagger}|\phi\rangle|^2
\end{align*}

Then if $E = 0$, we have our result. But this doesn't seem valid if $\langle \phi |\phi \rangle = \infty$.

I was trying to think how to "fix" the argument..

Maybe we could say that:

\begin{align*}
    H|\phi\rangle &= 0.
\end{align*}

Therefore

\begin{align*}
    \{Q, Q^{\dagger}\}|\phi\rangle &= 0
\end{align*}

Now hit both sides from the left with $\langle \phi|$.

On the left we get $|Q|\phi\rangle|^2 + |Q^{\dagger}\phi\rangle|^2$. On the right we get $\langle \phi | \cdot 0$, which one is tempted to say is 0. However, I am suspicious of this. (If trying to make a careful arguement) I think it doesn't make sense to actually write $\langle \phi|$ if $|\phi\rangle$ isn't normalisable (doesn't writing this rely on some Riesz theorem that applies to continuous linear functionals on a Hilbert space?). If $|\phi\rangle$ is not normalisable, this means it actually isn't in the Hilbert space. And so neither of the potential arguments are valid.

So my question is that if we find some function that H annihilates, do we need the function to be square integrable in order to conclude that both Q and $Q^{\dagger}$ necessarily will annihilate this function?

EDIT:

Another candidate argument I found (in the book "Differential Geometry through Supersymmetric Glasses, by Smilga) is to exchange $Q$ and $Q^{\dagger}$ for two Hermitian operators $Q_1 = Q + Q^{\dagger}$ and $Q_2 = \frac{1}{i}(Q - Q^{\dagger})$. Then $Q_1^2 = Q_2^2 = H$ and $\{Q_1, Q_2\} = 0.$

Now suppose $H|\phi\rangle = 0$. And suppose $Q_1|\phi\rangle \neq 0$. Since $Q_1$ and H commute and are Hermitian, we can simultaneously diagonalise them, and therefore we can assume that $|\phi\rangle$ is an eigenvector of $Q_1$. Therefore $Q_1|\phi\rangle = \lambda|\phi\rangle$, for some $\lambda > 0$. Now since $Q_1^2 = H$ we have that $H|\phi\rangle = \lambda^2 |\phi\rangle \neq 0$, which is a contradiction. So therefore $Q_1|\phi\rangle$ must actually be 0. So both $Q_1$ and $Q_2$ must annihilate the state, and so too must $Q$ and $Q^{\dagger}$.

This also seems a bit suspect if the state is not in the Hilbert space.

Comment: The state is normalized (or at least normalizable), so $\langle \phi | \phi \rangle = 1$. Non-normalizable states are not part of the Hilbert space.

Comment: I'm not asking about that case.

Comment: Then you need to explain your case better, because states which have $\langle \phi | \phi \rangle = \infty$ are not standard in physics. More context is required.

Comment: There's nothing else to prove. The moment you say $H\phi=0$ you are automatically saying that there exists a $\phi$ in the Hilbert space with that property. If this is not what you are saying you need to articulate more.

Comment: If I have a Hamiltonian H, and I find some function $\phi$ (that isn't square integrable) such that $H\phi$ = 0, then is there some way to argue that $Q\phi = Q^{\dagger}\phi = 0$? I am aware of the above arguments in the case where $\phi$ is an element of the Hilbert space, and suspected the arguments above didn't apply for non-normalisable $\phi$. However, I was wondering if there was some way to make the argument work for non-normalisable $\phi$.

Comment: But... .........         Why?

Comment: ↑↑↑ +1 ........

Comment: Imagine I had a Hamiltonian, and supercharges, and had a non-normalisable function, that is annihilated by H, like I described above. And say I found that neither Q nor Q^{\dagger} annihilated the function. And say I was surprised by this, because I had thought this necessarily followed from H annihilating the function.  I thought maybe I had made a calculation error, but didn't find any. Then I checked the proofs above, and suspected they didn't apply. But just because the proofs above don't apply in the case I'm asking about, doesn't mean there is no proof in the case I am asking about.

Comment: @Gleeson - what I think cosmos is asking (as am I) is why are you possibly interested in states that are not normalizable?

Comment: I'm confused like others in the comments...Aren't all elements of a finite-dimensional Hilbert space are normalizable, and aren't infinite-dimensional Hilbert spaces always defined as a normalizable subset of something, e.g., square-integrable functions $\mathcal{H} = L^2 (\mathbb{R}) = \ell^2 (\mathbb{N})$?Moreover, the operators are defined with respect to that Hilbert space...there exists a complete set of states onto which those operators can be decomposed, all of which are normalizable. The eigenstates of $Q$ and $H$ (including eigenvalue 0) must be normalizable. Am I missing something?